# Is there a more elegant way to find where a value fits in a range of values?

Tags: python

I am writing some code that takes in a number and gives that number a score. For example:

```
    if rev >= 300000000:
        return 10 # this is the score
    elif rev >= 200000000 and rev < 300000000:
        return 7
    elif rev >= 100000000 and rev < 200000000:
        return 5
    elif rev >= 30000000 and rev < 100000000:
        return 3
    else:
        return 1
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? I'm new to programming and I couldn't think of another way to search this.

Comment: You could just do `elif 200000000 =< rev < 300000000:`, but @Prune's is even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code is redundant: you repeat several value checks.  Instead:

```
if rev >= 300000000:
    return 10 # this is the score
elif rev >= 200000000:
    return 7
elif rev >= 100000000:
    return 5
elif rev >= 30000000:
    return 3
else:
    return 1
```

Now, generalize the problem: make a list of cutoffs and corresponding scores:

```
cutoff = [
    (3e8, 10),
    (2e8,  7),
    (1e8,  5),
    (3e7,  3),
    (0e1,  1)
]
```

Iterate through this list, checking `rev` against the cutoff value.  When you fail a ">=" check, return the previous point value.

Implementation is left as an exercise for the student.  Look out for the end-of-list case, too.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer provided by Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013317/5747944) is good for iterating over your ranges and the expected outputs.

I'll add to this by saying you can replace this:

```py
elif rev >= 200000000 and rev < 300000000
```

With

```py
elif rev in range(200000000, 300000000):
    ...
```

The *contains* operator (used for `in`) for `range` objects does basically the equivalent operation, provided you're not using floating point values.

Although in Prune's answer, this is obviated because you don't actually need the range.

Comment: Or also `elif 200 <= rev <= 300` (just imagine the extra zeroes). Python conveniently makes comparison operators chainable.

Comment: Yeah @CrazyChucky this is probably better if you expect values might be anything other than integers since `in range(...)` won't apply to floating point values within the range.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your values in an array and traverse it based on the numbers of other array. For optimal result, use a ordered array and a binary search. Luckily numpy get us covered

```
import numpy as np

values = [3e7, 1e8, 2e8, 3e8] # Must be sorted ascending
scores = [1, 3, 5, 7, 10] # One more element than values

return scores[np.searchsorted(values, rev, side='right')]
```

Comment: Edit: added `side='right'` for the case in which rev is equal to a value in values  `(if rev >= 300000000)`. The default is `side=left` which would be equivalent to `(if rev > 300000000)`